# Notation for greatest value a variable can be

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, maxima-minima

I'd like to know if there is a notation for a term or pronumeral is the highest value it can be (usually in terms of an equation or equality)

For Example:

Pretend "??" is such notation.
$$y=-x^2+1$$$$y??$$
What is the value of y?
The answer is obviously $y=1$ however is there a correct notation for this.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply $\max(y)$, the *maximum* of $y$.

To say $m$ is the largest value, we say $$m=\max_{x\in\mathbb R}\{1-x^2\},$$ *i.e.*, "$m$ is the maximum over real $x$ of the set of numbers of the form $1-x^2$".

Comment: To say y is its highest value, would you write: y = max(y)?

Comment: No, we say $$y=\max_{x\in\mathbb R}\{1-x^2\},$$ *i.e.*, "$y$ is the maximum over real $x$ of the set of numbers of the form $1-x^2$".

Comment: But, this maximum value should not be denoted by $y$, because the letter $y$ has already been used in the equation $y=-x^2 +1$.

Comment: @littleO Why not? It can easily be treated as simultaneous equations. Right?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum of a function is denoted as

$$\max_xf(x),$$ where the lower $x$ indicates on which variable(s) you optimize, and possibly in what range.

The notation

$$\arg\max_xf(x)$$ denotes the value of the variable for which that maximum is reached.

Comment: Is this the right notation or the other answer? I'm not exactly sure which to choose as answer.

Comment: @CowNecromancer: there is no difference !